# How to create fixed length dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

Creating a dataframe to update last three days price.

```
#Initial value with prices
price_3days=pd.DataFrame({'Day_of_month': [1,2,3], 'Price': [1000, 1100, 1200]})

#Price to be updated
Day_of_month_today=4
Price_today=1300

if (Day_of_month_today > price_3days['Day_of_month'].iloc[-1]):
    new_row=pd.DataFrame({'Day_of_month': [Day_of_month_today], 'Price': [Price_today]})
price_3days.drop(price_3days.head(1).index, inplace=True)
price_3days.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
price_3days=price_3days.append(new_row)
price_3days.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  
print(price_3days)

#Result

Day_of_month  Price
0             2   1100
1             3   1200
2             4   1300
```

List not updating when I enter next day of month and price, only last day is updated.
How can I update the list with last three days entry.
I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't missunderstood your question completely, your code is doing the right thing. You are deleting the first (oldest) row, and the new row is appended. Nonetheless, it is not very efficient to update a pd.DataFrame with `.append`, especially if you doing it multiple times, because pandas has to copy all the data over and over again.

Here is your code, with some optimisation. You can ommit the first `.reset_index`. And you can use so called *chained assignment*, where you connect all alterations of your DataFrame with a `.` (I enclosed all the statements with`()`, so one can split them over multiple lines).

```
#Initial value with prices
price_3days=pd.DataFrame({'Day_of_month': [1,2,3], 'Price': [1000, 1100, 1200]})

#Price to be updated
Day_of_month_today=4
Price_today=1300

if (Day_of_month_today > price_3days['Day_of_month'].iloc[-1]):
    new_row=pd.DataFrame({'Day_of_month': [Day_of_month_today], 'Price':[Price_today]})
    price_3days = (price_3days.drop(price_3days.head(1).index)
                  .append(new_row)
                  .reset_index(drop=True))
```

But maybe a dict will serve you more. If you add more information, what you wand to achieve, I can give you more advice, about how to implement a different solution.

Comment: I will be entering values for "Day_of_month_today" and
"Price_today" daily. and  my dataframe should show entries of last three days.

Comment: With this code only 3rd row is getting updated. I want 3rd row to be in place of 2nd and 2nd row in place of 1st row whenever a new entry is made.

Comment: When I execute your code or my version, all 3 rows are updated. The posted result in your code example also shows the updated dataFrame. Did I miss something fundamental? I mean, the first row is droped. Therefore, the former 2nd row is now the 1st row, and the former 3rd row is now the 2nd row. Then, the new row is appended, and the index is reset to (0,1,2).